# KafkaProducer not successfully sending message into the queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have built a small testing environment on my Windows PC and write down the following code for testing kafka (using kafka_2.10:0.9.0.1 from org.apache.kafka).

```
package iii.functiontesting;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;


/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class test4
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException
    {
        Properties producerProps=new Properties();
        producerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        producerProps.put("serializer.class",org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put("key.serializer",org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put("value.serializer",org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class.getName());
        producerProps.put("request.required.acks","1");
        KafkaProducer<String,String> kafkawriter= new KafkaProducer<String,String>(producerProps);
        ProducerRecord<String,String> msg=new ProducerRecord<>("TEST3","ImKey","teststring1");
        kafkawriter.send(msg);
    }
}
```

I use the following command to check whether the message is correctly written into the queue

> D:\Work\kafkaenv\kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1\bin\windows>.\kafka-console-consumer.bat
>   --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic TEST3 --from-beginning

However, I found that the kafka-console-consumer shows nothing.

I have doubted that my kafka server doesn't run properly, so I use console-producer to test.

> D:\Work\kafkaenv\kafka_2.10-0.9.0.1\bin\windows>.\kafka-console-producer.bat
>   --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic TEST3
>
> aaaaa

This time I can see the aaaaa is clearly shown under the console-consumer.
I cannot figure out what happens.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to call either `KafkaProducer#flush` [or] `KafkaProducer#close` method before terminating the program.

Actually, the producer buffers the records before sending it to the broker. See `buffer.memory` and `batch.size` in the [Kafka Producer configuration](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs)

```
kafkawriter.send(msg);
kafkawriter.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. The message has been properly sent after adding flush(). I think I need to study the kafka configuration more deeply. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So what's the purpose of calling `flush` here? My code doesn't have this but still working.